# VBA copy matching values from list to calendar

Tags: excel, vba, list, calendar

I am working on a dashboard for certain projects.
However, I can't seem to get my problem fixed so here it is:

I have two sheets, one with my data list and one that shows some kind of calendar.

https://imgshare.io/images/2020/07/16/Annotation-2020-07-16-125707.png

https://imgshare.io/images/2020/07/16/Annotation-2020-07-16-125724.png

What I want to do is check if the start date in the list is in the range of that week and then paste all task names that do fall in that week, posted below eachother in the calendar.

Who can help me?

Comment: Your data cannot be compared by calculating the order of the weeks. This is because there are overlapping weeknums for each year. The first year should be checked to see if it is the same, and whether it falls within the same week of the same year. Then you need to make sure that the date is the same week. You should use the content  [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60732616/get-a-weeknumbers-end-date-using-excel-macro/60733488#60733488) to check if it is the same weeknum.

Answer (score 0):

You could go down the route of having an indicator flag like this:
`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A4,$C$1:$L$1,0)),"N","Y")`
where A4 is the date you want to find in the C1:L1 columns. You could put that in to VBA by doing this:

```
LastRow = 100
sheets("Sheet1").range("B4").value = "=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A4,$C$1:$L$1,0)),""N"",""Y"")"
sheets("Sheet1")range("B4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B4:B" & LastRow)
```

or use a loop but loops can be time consuming. This loop is going through column header by column header, to find the matching date. Then you can decide what to do after the loop if the DateFinder is true or false.

```
Dim DateFinder as boolean
DateFinder = False
i=2
Do While DateFinder = false and sheets("Sheet1").cells(3,i).value <> ""
 if sheets("Sheet1").range("A4").value = sheets("Sheet1").cells(3,i).value then
  datefinder = true
 end if
 i = i + 1
Loop
```