# Excel VBA - change date/week number to start and end date of the week

Tags: excel, vba, date

Im using this excel worksheet function to get the range of a week (start and end) from the date ex.
14.08.2020 gives me  10.08-16.08. Im trying to convert it to VBA function, because it will be easier to use but i have total brain blackout. Can you tell me what im doing wrong?

Excel:

```
=TEXT(DATE(2020;1;1)+(WEEKNUM(D1;2)-1)*7-WEEKDAY(DATE(2020;1;1);2)+1;"DD.MM")&"-"&TEXT(DATE(2020;1;1)+(WEEKNUM(D1;2)-1)*7-WEEKDAY(DATE(2020;1;1);2)+7;"DD.MM")
```

VBA:

```
Function dog(x As String) As String

dog = WorksheetFunction.Text(DateSerial(2020, 1, 1) + (WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(A1, 2) - 1) * 7 - Weekday(DateSerial(2020, 1, 1), vbMonday) + 1, "DD.MM") & "-" & WorksheetFunction.Text(DateSerial(2020, 1, 1) + (WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(A1, 2) - 1) * 7 - Weekday(DateSerial(2020, 1, 1), vbMonday) + 7, "DD.MM")
End Function
```

It just doesn't work (ARG) or (NAME?)

Comment: refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60732616/get-a-weeknumbers-end-date-using-excel-macro/60733488#60733488)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a WeekNumber's end date using excel macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60732616/get-a-weeknumbers-end-date-using-excel-macro)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use native VBA functions:

```
Option Explicit
Function dog(x As Date) As String
    Dim dStartOfWeek As Date 'a Monday
    Dim dEndOfWeek As Date   'a Sunday
    
dStartOfWeek = x - Weekday(x) + 2
dEndOfWeek = dStartOfWeek + 6

dog = Format(dStartOfWeek, "dd.mm-") & Format(dEndOfWeek, "dd.mm")

End Function
```

- Is there some reason you declared your input argument to be of type string?
- If you are getting a `#NAME?` error on the worksheet, you probably didn't put your UDF into a regular module, or you have multiple objects named `dog`